# Beamer: \nonumber equivalent for slides?

Tags: beamer, numbering

Is there an equivalent command to `\nonumber` when one doesn't want to include certain slides in the numbering? I would like to leave outline and title slides out of my numbering, and instead just number slides with actual content. Other workarounds would be nice to know about as well.

Edit: Since a MWE example was requested, here is one. Suppose I have a title page and two other slides. The code below gives a slide counter that goes up to 3, and the title slide is slide 1. I would prefer to have the title slide not be numbered, the counter go up to 2, and the the numbering start at the slide after the title. Here is some code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
 {
   \usetheme{Dresden}
 }

 \setbeamertemplate
 {footline}{\quad\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\strut\quad} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some actual content here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some more actual content here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so others can have something concrete to work with?

Answer (score 141):

Since [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) version 3.08, there is an undocumented option `noframenumbering` that doesn't increase the slide counter for the frame it is used on. This has the advantage that you don't have to manipulate the `framenumber` counter by hand. It is used like this:

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
 \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Note: If you have a frame title, you need to place [..] *before* the frame title. For example, I'm doing this to not count my outline pages:

  `\begin{frame}<beamer>[noframenumbering]{Outline}`

Comment: I followed the exact instruction, but it does not work for me. My second slide still shows the slide count as 2/50, not 1/50. Any clues?

Comment: Does your first and second slide belong to same the same ``frame``? I have the same issue, when I used ``noframenumbering`` along with ``allowframebreaks`` the second slide is counted in the page numbering

Comment: For me this adds a 0 where there used to be a 1. This is even worse.

Comment: @MERose this can be avoided by removing the footer entirely from the title page by adding `plain,` before `noframenumbering` i.e. `\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]` etc

Comment: An amazingly simple solution to address the question and my own dilemma adding support slides at the end, just in case they come in handy to address a question or expand on a subject if there is time.

Answer (score 25):

I usually just modify the `framenumber` counter using `\setcounter` to reset the frame number and `\addtocounter` with e.g. -1 to compensate for a slide which should not count. Usually you also want to hide the frame counter for these slides.

For example I used the following to don't number the title frame:

```
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\insertframenumber}{}
 \begin{frame}
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
  \titlepage
 \end{frame}
\endgroup
```

One issue with the frame number hiding is that theme use something like `\insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber` and so you can't get rid of the `/` that easy. I copied my theme for the lower bar and replaced that part with an own macro `\insertframenumberratio` which I set to empty to suppress the display. Alternatively you can still display it which then shows the number of the next slide. Usually people won't notice or mind that.

Comment: I usually just put a `*` in place of the current framenumber for things like outline etc.

Comment: @CarstenThiel: Yes, I also thought about doing that. It is probably the easiest thing to do.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]{}

\begin{document}

{\setbeamertemplate{footline}{} 
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
} %this removes the footline from title page

\addtocounter{page}{-1}  %the next frame will start from number 1 instead of 2
...

\appendix %all the frame after this line will not be included in the TOTAL PAGE count
%your appendix frames go here   
\begin{frame}{References}
...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same with other answers?

Comment: @percusse: it shows how to remove the footline from the first slide!

Answer (score 5):

For this specific example, I would just relocate the definition of the beamer template - `\setbeamertemplate` - to *after* the first slide. Additionally, for the `framecounter` to be accurate (using Martin's answer), add `\addtocounter{framecounter}{-1}` at the same location:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
 {
   \usetheme{Dresden}
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \titlepage
\end{frame}

 \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
 \setbeamertemplate
 {footline}{\quad\hfill\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\strut\quad} 

\begin{frame}
Some actual content here
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some more actual content here
\end{frame}

\end{document}​
```

[image]