# Don't skip framenumbers in beamer in handout mode

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, counters

Consider the following beamer example below. Is it possible to adjust this, that Frame 4 has framenumber 3 on the handout (and not 4 in my example). In other words the numbering in the handout should be as the code of frame 3 would be commented out (and not just have the option ).

```
\documentclass[handout,gray]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\scriptsize{\vspace*{0.3cm}\hspace*{0.3cm}\insertframenumber}}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Frame 1}
   Frame 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<display:0>
   \frametitle{Frame 2}
   Frame 2
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}<handout:0>
   \frametitle{Frame 3}
   Frame 3
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
   \frametitle{Frame 4}
   Frame 4
\end{frame}   
\end{document}
```

[image: Frames]

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand.  In your example, the numbers are hard-coded (not automatically generated) so you could do something like `\alt<display>{4}{3}` to put a `4` when in `display` mode and `3` otherwise (ie `handout` mode, though `article` would also get the `3`).  Would this help, or is the real case more complicated?

Comment: @AndrewStacey The real example has a lot more frames and a lot more frames which should be skipped for the handout. So it's not a good idea to generate the framenumbers manually for the handout. Note that I don't need any numbers for display. I just want to have consecutive numbering for the handout frames (1,2,3,4,... without skipping a number though some frames are not on the handout).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) version 3.08, there is [an undocumented option `noframenumbering`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49805/3323) that doesn't increase the slide counter for the current frame. So if you want to exclude a single frame from the numeration and the handout, you can use

```
\begin{frame}<handout:0>[noframenumbering]
  ...
\end{frame}
```

To automate this, i. e. to exclude all the frame that aren't displayed in the current mode (`handout`, `trans`) from the numeration, you can patch the internal `beamer` command responsible for generating the frames:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\beamer@@@@frame}{\alt<#1>{}{\beamer@noframenumberingtrue}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Include this code somewhere in the preamble (that's between `\documentclass{beamer}` and `\begin{document}`) of your document. It uses the overlay command `\alt` to activate `noframenumbering` on every slide which isn't displayed.

#### Example code:

```
\documentclass[handout,gray]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\scriptsize{\vspace*{0.3cm}\hspace*{0.3cm}\insertframenumber}}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49806/3323
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\beamer@@@@frame}{\alt<#1>{}{\beamer@noframenumberingtrue}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Absolute frame number: 1\\
    Frame number in presentation: \insertframenumber
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    Absolute frame number: 2\\
    Frame number in presentation: \insertframenumber
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<handout:0>
    Absolute frame number: 3\\
    Frame number in presentation: \insertframenumber
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    Absolute frame number: 4\\
    Frame number in presentation: \insertframenumber
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

#### Result (click on the image to see it full-size):

[image: output of the example handout with continuous frame numbering]

Comment: This looks like a wonderful answer, however I have a slight doubt about the details, given that `\pretocmd` is suppoesed (per the `etoolbox` documentation) to take 4 arguments. Are you sure you did not mismatch your braces?

Comment: Answering my own comment: I fixed your solution in the following way: `\pretocmd{\beamer@@@@frame}{\alt<#1>{}{\beamer@noframenumberingtrue}}{}{}}%`. Of course, this does not work in a macro (because it does not like the `#`). The usual trick (which I just tested and it works) is then to do something like
    `\def\hideInvisible{\lccode\`\~=\`\#\lowercase{%
    \pretocmd{\beamer@@@@frame}{\alt<~1>{}{\beamer@noframenumberingtrue}}{}{}}%
    \lccode\`\~=0}`
(Doubling the `#` did not work for me).

Comment: @Circonflexe You are right, `\pretocmd` has two further arguments to execute code when patching succeeds or fails. I did not notice the error as the code compiles as is, using `\makeatother` as the code for success and the following empty line (equivalent to a `\par`) as the code for failure. Thank you for the hint, I have updated the answer to use `\pretocmd` correctly.

Comment: As of Feb 2023, is the patch with `\pretocmd` still working for you? It used to work for me, but doesn't anymore... maybe I have messed up something?