# More than one option within a frame

Tags: beamer

I'm using `beamer` to create frames. I don't want frame numbers and I want to allow for frame breaks:

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{My title}
```

does work, and

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{My title}
```

How do I combine both?

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering allowframebreaks]{My title}
```

nor

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering][allowframebreaks]{My title}
```

work.

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, allowframebreaks]{My title}
```

only enables the first option.

Comment: Which theme are you using? You mean you want to suppress the numbering from the footline?

Comment: I'm using Madrid theme. I want to suppress the numbering in the frame title. Suggested answer does not work: \begin{frame}[noframenumbering, allowframebreaks]{My title}

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to say

```
\begin{frame}[options,separated,by,commas]{title}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,allowframebreaks]{Title}

  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However `noframenumbering` is not an option that removes the continuation numbers from these slides.  For that you should adjust the beamer template for `frametitle continuation`:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
```

either globally or restricted to a group for the particular frame:

[image: Unnumbered sample]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lipsum} %for dummy text

\begin{document}

{\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,allowframebreaks]{Title}

  \lipsum[1-4]
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, suggested answer still doesn't suppress the number right in front of frame's title. I just ran your code and got Title I, Title II and Title III in each of the frame's title.

Comment: Answer updated to include this...

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I just wonder then what `noframenumbering` means.

Comment: @cacosomoza `noframenumbering` prevents the incrementing the frame counter on the current frame.  A theme such as `Boadzilla` shows these numbers in the footline.  When there are frame breaks the counter still increments in the subsequent parts of the frame, so it does not seem to be doing anything useful.  I included in the answer as it was the option you mentioned in your question.