# Suppress output of slide numbers for slides without number for Beamer

Tags: beamer

There is a question about how not to number some slides: [Beamer: \nonumber equivalent for slides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30461/beamer-nonumber-equivalent-for-slides)

However the slides themselves still have their number printed.
How can I suppress output of that as well?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Dresden} 

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}

\begin{document}

%do not want slide number here
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
 \titlepage 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some actual content here
\end{frame}

%and here
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
{\Huge Section 2}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some more actual content here
\end{frame}

%and possibly on 20 more slides 
%without specifying format for each of special slides
%every time

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide the community with a minimal example that replicates your current problem? The reference to "slides" and "frames" may be confusing to some users.

Comment: On way is `\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]`, but this also removes the headline. To keep the headline, but remove the frame number, temporally make an empty footline `{
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
 \titlepage 
\end{frame}
}`

Comment: Yes, this can help if the number of slides is not too large. Could you please make this an answer? However it is not the full solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically three options, how to get rid of the framenumbers:

> 1. remove head- and footline via:

```
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering, plain]...
```

> 2. temporarily clear the footline

```
 { \setbeamertemplate{footline}{} \begin{frame}[noframenumbering] \titlepage \end{frame} }
```

> 3. temporarily redefining the footline

This heavily depends on the used outer theme. With `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}` used in the MWE this brings no advantage compared to option 2.

---

To make this automatic for a large number of frames, one can define custom keys. The following example illustrates, how this could work with option 2.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\defbeamertemplate{footline}{nonum}{%
    \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}
}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{frame}{%
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]{}
}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{nonum}[true]{%
    \setbeamertemplate{footline}[nonum]%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[nonum]
        Removeframenumber
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        normal frame
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say the best thing is to link `noframenumbering` to suppress the print; this can be done using the following toggle:

```
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{
\ifbeamer@noframenumbering
\else
  \usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}%
  \hbox to 2cm{\hfil\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber\hfil}
  \vskip2pt\relax
\fi%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @barbarabeeton many thanks.