# Beamer presentation with no numbers in several slides (title page, outline slide, highlighting current section)

Tags: beamer, page-numbering, presentations

```
\documentclass[french]{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{links}{HTML}{2A1B81}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,linkcolor=,urlcolor=links}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}      % o1r try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{beaver} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{serif}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.7\paperwidth}{}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{1.5em}
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,mathtools,marvosym,graphicx,MnSymbol,wasysym,epstopdf,
scalerel,gensymb}   

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset
{
    language=[LaTeX]TeX,
    breaklines=true,
    basicstyle=\tt\scriptsize,
    %commentstyle=\color{green}
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    %stringstyle=\color{black}
    identifierstyle=\color{magenta},
}


\settowidth{\leftmargini}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\addtolength{\leftmargini}{\labelsep}
\settowidth{\leftmarginii}{\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\addtolength{\leftmarginii}{1.5\labelsep}


%Pour le TITLEPAGE
\title[Exposé]{CONCOURS}
\subtitle{Exposé de candidature
}
\author[DSA]{Joe Smith}
\titlegraphic{\vspace{-15pt}\includegraphics[height=0.1\textheight,keepaspectratio=true]{logopolito}\hspace*{3cm}~%
  \includegraphics[height=0.1\textheight,keepaspectratio=true]{logopolito}
   \hspace*{3cm}~%
   \includegraphics[height=0.1\textheight,keepaspectratio=true]{logopolito}
}
\institute[AU]{{\Large Null part Université}\\\vspace{5pt}Blablabla\\\vspace{5pt}Blablabla\\\vspace{5pt}{Blablabla\\\vspace{5pt}
Blabla\\Blablablabla}}

\date{}

\newif\ifshowtoc
\showtoctrue% toggles to show the toc

\AtBeginSection{%
\ifshowtoc
\begin{frame}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection, subsectionstyle=show/show/hide]
\end{frame}
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Plan}
  \tableofcontents[hidesubsections]
  % You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section[CV]{Curriculum Vitae}
\begin{frame}{Curriculum Vitae résumé}
\begin{block}{Diplômes}
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{Parcours post-doctoral}
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\end{itemize}
\end{block}


\end{frame}

\section{Enseignement}
\subsection{Enseignements réalisés}
\begin{frame}{Avignon Université, depuis se 2016, 563 heures Eq. TD}


\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Avignon Université, Répartition des enseignements}

\end{frame}
\subsection{Projet d'enseignement}

\section{Recherche}
\subsection{Contexte}
\subsection{Projets réalisés}
\subsection{Projet de recherche}
\section{Conclusion}
\showtocfalse
\section*{Remerciements}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{\MakeUppercase{Je vous remercie de votre attention.}}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

1/ How can I have the total number of slides in the Title Slide ONLY?
[image]

2/ There is one slide with outline.
[image]
How can I have this slide not depicting the X/Y pages on the right corner ? I also want that this slide does not count to the total number of slides.

3/ Before each section a slide appears with current active section.
[image]
How can I have this slide (and the other slides highlighting future actual sections) not depicting the X/Y pages on the right corner ? I also want that the highlighting current actual slides do not count to the total number of slides.

Comment: You might be interested in [Beamer: \nonumber equivalent for slides?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30461/134144)

Comment: I would combine https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49805/36296 with the `plain` frame option